# "error=2, No such file or directory" when Hosting an executable within Android application

Tags: android, arm, executable

### Problem Description

I'm am working with an android application that is hosting an arm executable located in the internal storage (/data/data/APPNAME/files/EXECUTABLE).

When I check the file like this :

```
filePath = context.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/SMILExtract-static"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file " + filePath);
```

the shell output is:

```
/data/user/0/app.me.phonestudy/files/SMILExtract-static: ELF shared object, 32-bit LSB arm, dynamic (/usr/lib/libc.so.1), for Android 21, built by NDK r15c (4203891), stripped
```

so the file must obviously exist. 
Yet when I make the file executable and execute it:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/chmod 777 " + filePath);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);
```

I get this error:

```
04-04 22:26:41.774 24708-24896/app.me.phonestudy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: data Processing Thread
                                                               Process: app.me.phonestudy, PID: 24708
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/app.me.phonestudy/files/SMILExtract-static": error=2, No such file or directory

                                                                Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/app.me.phonestudy/files/SMILExtract-static": error=2, No such file or directory
                                                                   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:692)
                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:525)
                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:422)

                                                                Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
                                                                   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
                                                                   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:128)
                                                                   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:692) 
                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:525) 
                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:422) 
                                                                   at
```

### Question

Why cant the file be found when it obviously exists at the given path?

My only lead is this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists which mentions compatibility issues when trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system that doesn't have 32-bit support installed. 
 Since this post is not specifically for android systems it didnt really help me in solving my problem.

I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe either it can't find the material, or you didn't install it correctly.

Comment: Since your question was what could cause this problem, I believe that is what is causing it.